# How to fix RecognitionEngine error on android app using API.ai

Tags: java, android-studio, android-manifest, manifest, dialogflow-es

I've been following some tutorials on how to make an app with API.ai integrated with it. But so far, unlike the tutorials, it gives me an error when I apply the Recognition Engine. This is the code on my Manifest.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import ai.api.AIConfiguration;
import ai.api.AIListener;
import ai.api.android.AIService;
import ai.api.model.AIError;
import ai.api.model.AIResponse;
import ai.api.model.Result;
import ai.api.ui.AIButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AIListener{

    private AIService aiService;
    TextView t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AIService aiService;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            makeRequest();
        }

        final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration("CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN",
                AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
                AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);
        aiService = AIService.getService(this, (ai.api.android.AIConfiguration) config);
        aiService.setListener(this);

    }
```

This line of code: AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);
I have all the dependencies that API.ai requests to add to the app gradle. 
It says "Cannot resolve the symbol". Does anyone know why this error occurs or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "import ai.api.android.AIConfiguration;"